# Referencing Cookie with jQuery in content_for tag -- Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cookies

I am trying to reference my cookie inside a `content_for` tag. I keep getting the error - 
 `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

I have the following snippet of code:

```
<% content_for :script_onload do %>
  //irrelevant code
  var mixpanelCookie = JSON.parse($.cookie('mp_mixpanel_development'));
  mixpanel.people.identify(mixpanelCookie.distinct_id);
<% end %>
```

I have tried wrapping the code inside the `content_for` tag with

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is there a way for me to either reference the cookie without jQuery or include jQuery in the `content_for` tag?

Comment: Have you tried adding the jquery reference in your template `<head>`?  Adding it on-load isn't going to cut it, since it will be loaded asynchronously.  Unless you delay the rest of the execution until that completes loading as well... but why bother?  Just place it in <head>.

Comment: @PinnyM If I include it in my head, how do I reference the library itself? Meaning, would I do something like `jQuery.cookie`

Comment: what do you mean by 'reference the library itself'?  The `jQuery` object (aliased as `$`) will be created allowing you full access to jQuery in any script executed thereafter.  So, you can do `$.cookie` as you have it now.  That is, unless you have some other library loaded that already uses `$` (e.g. Prototype).

Comment: @PinnyM Thanks for the explanation. It looks like the jQuery library is already being loaded in the `<head>` so I'll have to figure out why it is not aliased as `$`

Comment: check your console. as long as jQuery is referenced, $ will be accessible, unless you have other loading errors.